# Confiurging lighttpd for serving static csv files

Tags: csv, http-status-code-404, lighttpd, static-site, papaparse

I'm using `lightpd` for debugging on my development machine. All content is static. When I try to load a csv file using [Papaparse](https://www.papaparse.com/). I get the following error in Firefox

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8080/thing/rt_data.csv. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

All my web debugging is taking place in `/home/mm/Software/webby/` and `lighttpd` is running in that directory. The files are all in a subdirectory `/home/mm/Software/webby/thing`. The JS code is

```
      Papa.parse("http://127.0.0.1:8080/thing/rt_data.csv"
         {download: true,
         dynamicTyping: true,
         complete: csvprocess});
```

The function `cvsprocess` is called when the data has been loaded.

`lighttpd.conf` is:

```
   server.tag = ""
   server.document-root = "/home/mm/Software/webby/"
   setenv.add-response-header = ( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" =>
           "http://home/mm/Software/webby/")
   server.upload-dirs = ( "/home/mm/webby/hoststuff" )
   server.errorlog = "/home/mm/Software/webby/hoststuff/error.log"
   accesslog.filename = "/home/mm/Software/webby/hoststuff/access.log"
   compress.cache-dir = "/home/mm/Software/PithyVis/hoststuff/compress/"
```

Only the modified lines are shown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT

I changed the access control to

```
   setenv.add-response-header = ( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*")
```

I still have a 404 error, but the message is different:

```
   [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 18ms]
```

Answer (score 0):

`"http://home/mm/Software/webby/"` != `"http://127.0.0.1:8080/..."`

Access-Control-Allow-Origin should be a URI (or `*` or `null`), not a mishmash of http:// and a filesystem path.